# Testing Grommet UI Compents with Jest in a NextJS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, grommet

I've got a NextJS project that uses Grommet UI. When I try and test it using Jest I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageHeader')` (see full stack trace at the end).

I wrap a Layout with the Grommet component like this:

```
type LayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode,
};

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <Grommet plain>
      <Page kind="narrow">
        <PageContent>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </PageContent>
      </Page>
    </Grommet>
  )
}
```

and then my app.ts file looks like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Layout>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Layout>
};
```

Then I have a basic component that contains Gommet's `PageHeader` component:

```
const RegionDetail: React.FC<{ title: string }> =  ({title}) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <PageHeader title={ title }></PageHeader>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Then the test itself is failing on the first line:

```
describe('RegionDetails', () => {
  test('Region Details', () => {
    render(<RegionDetail title="test" />);
  });
});
```

If I add the `Gromet` component to the test it passes:

```
describe('RegionDetails', () => {
  test('Region Details', () => {
    render(<Grommet plain><RegionDetail title="test" /></Grommet>);
  });
});
```

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageHeader')]
    at reportException (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:343:9)
    at invokeEventListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:276:3)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:223:9)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:241:34)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12) {
detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageHeader')
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/grommet/components/PageHeader/PageHeader.js:44:41
    at renderWithHooks (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateForwardRef (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19226:20)
    at beginWork (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21636:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:340:25)
    at invokeEventListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:276:3)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:223:9)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:241:34)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
    at workLoopSync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25738:74)
    at flushActQueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
    at act (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2582:11)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:63:25
    at renderRoot (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:159:26)
    at render (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:246:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/test/regions/RegionDetails.spec.tsx:34:11)
    at Promise.then.completed (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:333:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:259:10)
    at _callCircusTest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:277:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at _runTest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:209:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:97:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:91:9)
    at run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:31:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:135:21)
    at jestAdapter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:92:19)
    at runTestInternal (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:411:16)
    at runTest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:499:34)
    at Object.worker (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:133:12),
type: 'unhandled exception'
}
```

Comment: That means you need to wrap your components with `Grommet` during the tests too. That's probably because the `Grommet` component acts as a context provider for the other Grommet components, like `PageHeader`.

Comment: I expect you're right @juliomalves - I guess I was just wondering if there was some configuration in Jest that might mean I don't have to add the `Grommet` tags to every test.

Comment: You could build a custom `render` function that would wrap `Grommet` around each component you're testing, then reuse that on every test.